# Freeradius case sentivitity of letters

Tags: linux, networking, freeradius

I have VirtualMachine with freeradius server (3.0). I am using the authorization file which contains my PPPoE users. The problem seems to be the username: the login is in UPPER CASE which collides with the incoming username.

I can't manually change this because my config file is generated by LMS (Lan Management System - I won`t change anything in code). Is there any method to turn off case-sensitivity in freeradius?

This is my config:

```
EXAMPLEUSER Cleartext-Password := "ExamplePassword01@"
        Framed-Protocol = PPP,
        Framed-IP-Address = 192.168.0.33,
        Framed-IP-Netmask = 255.255.255.0,
        Service-Type = Framed-User,
        Mikrotik-Rate-Limit = "30000k/30000k 30000k/30000k 30000k/30000k 1/1 1 30000k/30000k"
```

I tried to find information about case-sensitivity, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FreeRadius `expr` module does provide `toupper` and `tolower`.  You could convert the received username to "UPPER CASE" in the `authorize` section or in a policy.

Slightly modified example from the first link

```
authorize {
    update request {
        Stripped-User-Name := "%{toupper:%{User-Name}}"
    }
```

**links**

- [Suggestion "to just mash the User-Name" from the FreeRadius mailing list](https://lists.freeradius.org/pipermail/freeradius-users/2020-February/097517.html)
- [The example policy `canonicalization` has examples of changing attributes with `toupper`](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v3.0.x/raddb/policy.d/canonicalization#L79)
- [expr module documentation](https://networkradius.com/doc/3.0.10/raddb/mods-available/expr.html)